# Confused about a static function

Tags: c++, oop, static, static-methods

I got this small code snippet and I am a little confused why it works this way. When I call A::put_x(3), a doesn't change because it's a static function? Thanks!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    static int x;
    int y;
public:
    A(int i) { x = i; y = -i; }
    static int put_x(A a) { return x + a.y; }
};

int A::x = 5;
int main()
{
    A a(7);
    cout << A::put_x(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which `a` do you mean? And how do you check that whatever `a` you mean doesn't change? Besides, what do you mean when you say "a doesn't change"?

Answer (score 2):

It shows correct result.

Trace of static X changes:

1. Line 14, initialization of A::x, x == 5
2. Line 17, instance of A in main(), x == 7
3. Line 18, new temporary instance of A as result of casting integer: A(3), x == 3

When you call put_x, it calculates sum of x (now it's 3) and value y (-3) of temporary object.
Result is 0 as expected.